# Detecting fast-flowing data with serial port

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

300 items flow from a production band at a minute. Using an optical micrometer, with pyserial and qthread, I am trying to 200 receives per second. But I can not get it right as I expected. There is not a problem when I keep it fixed, but I can not get the correct result when the object is moving. I need to detect width of the item flowing fast with the serial port. How would you recommend a method for this?

Comment: Seems you get more`Data` as your `serial connection`could transfer. What does calculate **items *(bytes per Measurement)** results.

Comment: I try to get only 25 bytes per measurement. Serial port settings: baudrate = 115200, timeout = 0.0075

Comment: These results in **1,000** bits/sec. Far away from the baudrate limit.  But, have you counted  that you received 1,000 bits/sec?  Can you explain _"can not get the correct result"_ a bit more.

Comment: Never seen such a `timeout = 0.0075` value, try `timeout = 0`

Comment: I got it by trial-and-error to find the optimum value:) When I decrease the timeout, it occasionally breaks in the data stream.  For example, value, none, none, none, value, value, none ... etc.
"can not get the correct result" means that the incoming data is not in the range I expect. meaningless data.

Comment: For completion, please edit your Question and add your **stop bits, parity and flow control**. Double-check it's equal on both sides.   Does `value, none ...` mean `value` is one measurement = 25 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**:.  When I decrease the timeout, it occasionally breaks in the data stream.

Try the following, decrease down to 9600:.

```
Open port at “38400,8,E,1”, non blocking HW handshaking:

>>> ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 38400, timeout=0,
...                     parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, rtscts=1)
>>> s = ser.read(100)       # read up to one hundred bytes
...                         # or as much is in the buffer
```